# SQLAlchemy Session handling in a multi thread app

Tags: python, multithreading, session, sqlalchemy

I define my data model on module level like this

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine = create_engine('cx_oracle://username:password@dsn')
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

... data model located on engine
```

and then I start some threads like this

```
threads = []

# start threads
for i in range(4):

    # each thread needs it own session
    thread = threading.Thread(target=fn, args=(in, ))
    thread.start()
    threads.append(thread)

# wait for threads to finish
for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

where `fn(in)` is some method where I use `session = Session()`, which are then used for various purposes.

With this I get various errors, which only occurs sometimes. It can be

- `DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) DPI-1002: invalid OCI handle`
- `DBAPIError: (sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError) This Connection is closed`
- `InvalidRequestError: Session is already flushing`

I really don't know how to fix this issue though

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], especially the contents of `fn`.

Answer (score 0):

We have been having some similar issues with our application and cx_Oracle 6.x which was updated to use a new C interface to the Oracle OCI (ODPI-C) that has some references to that error in it's release notes. We downgraded cx_Oracle and the issue disappeared.